# cannot get product collection via dependency injection in version Magento: 2.2.1

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.2.1. I cannot get the product collection when i use dependency injection. I wonder if I have left out something that needs to be done. for example, do I need to feed the product object into the injection?

This is the code:

```
namespace Test\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); 
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

?

Then on my phtml page I do this:

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());     
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The page comes back with a black, no error messages, just a blank page.

However, if i use the object manager to get the product collection it works: 
**THE CODE BELOW WORKS**

```
public function getProduct()
    {    
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

        $collection = $productCollection->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->load();

        return $collection;

    }
```

Comment: Try to remove page size from DI than check., OR you can use `$collection->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc');` Make sure you have visible products, Check Answer by Monarch1.

Comment: why you have using different function on different sceneio `getProduct` and `getProductCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $collectionFactory;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory ) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory; }

public function yourMethod() {
    $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    foreach ($collection as $product){   
    enter code here
    }

    }
```

Comment: no no. you misunderstand. i dont want to use the object manager. i want to use dependency injection. my object manager works already. its the DI that does work

Comment: Paul, Please use updated function,

Comment: If you post code as an answer, please at least explain briefly what this code is doing and where it belongs. Answers with code but no
explanation are rarely useful.